# Regexp to replace star at beginning of line if preceding line doesn't begin with star

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to replace a star `*` or another specific char at the beginning of a line, but only if the previous line does not begin with the same character.

In other words to replace

```
Something.
* some bullet point
```

with

```
Something.

* some bullet point
```

I am trying with

```
s/\n[^\*](.+?)\n\*/\n$1\n\n*/ms;
```

but no result.

Ideally in perl - but I can probably translate from other languages

Comment: Maybe `s/^([^\n*].*)\n\*/$1\n\n*/m`? But make sure you read the whole text with linebreaks into a single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your regexp.

```
#!perl
use strict;

my $txt = <<EOT;
Something.
* some bullet point
EOT

$txt =~ s/^([^\*][^\n]*\n)\*/$1\n\*/mg;

print $txt;
```

works.

Answer (score 2):

If you're reading a file line by line, use a flag variable to remember whether the previous line started with an asterisk:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $previous;
while (<DATA>) {
    print "\n" if /^\*/ && ! $previous;
    $previous = /^\*/;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Something.
* some bullet point
* but keep this
```